# (Unity) Progress bar appearing backwards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a progress bar that shows how close the player is to the finish in a 3D area, but I can't figure out how to make it go in the correct direction rather than going backwards.

```cs
startNEnd = Vector3.Distance(start.transform.position, GameObject.Find("GoalPrefab(Clone)").transform.position);
playerNEnd = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, GameObject.Find("GoalPrefab(Clone)").transform.position);
progressBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3(playerNEnd/startNEnd, 1, 1);
```

(The X pivot point is set to 0)

How can I make it go the correct direction?

Comment: You could subtract your value from 1.  `1 - (playerNEnd / startNEnd)`

Comment: Still doesn't work, now it's just in the wrong position!

Comment: Turns out it was simply grabbing the wrong position, and it works now! Can you post your answer as an actual answer so that I can mark it? (The green checkmark thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invert the value by subtracting it from 1.

```
var progress = 1 - (playerNEnd / startNEnd);
```

This works for values that are constrained between 0 and 1.

```
1 - 0.75 = 0.25
1 - 0.50 = 0.50
1 - 0.25 = 0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try linear interpolation for better control over the values.

```
float progress = Mathf.Lerp(1f, 0f, playerNEnd / startNEnd);
progressBar.transform.localScale = new Vector3(progress, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work...